# Heroku javascript include issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently using the farbtastic-rails gem to embed color picker on my rails site. For that I have added

```
//= require farbtastic
```

to my application.js file,

as I am using rails 3.2.x, necessary javascripts come from asset pipeline which is present in gem directory.

The javascripts needed get included on local server, but I can't see the library there on my heroku server. I am not understanding the actual problem.

Is there any way to set up a local environment like production on heroku so that I can dig deeper in to problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check out this useful blogpost : http://neilmiddleton.com/heroku-asset-pipeline-faq/ Could help you in figuring out the problem.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy, thanks for your kind help. The resource link you provided made my work. Problem was with the assets precompilation. Please provide your comment in answer section, so that it can help to others as well.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to know it helped. I have added the same in the answer section as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a useful blogpost dealing with all the issues with Heroku / Asset Pipeline : http://neilmiddleton.com/heroku-asset-pipeline-faq/ Could be useful in figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To run in production mode

```
rails server -e production
```